# How to reduce width of HTML text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reduce the width of a piece of text under an image that only takes up about 50% of the screen, so I've tried using `style = width:50%` but for some reason, the width stays the same. 
[Here is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNA7P.jpg).
 I want it so that the caption is neatly contained under the image.
  What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Evelyn Lauder </h1>
  <h5 class="font-italic"> 1936-2011</h5>
  <img src=h ttp://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg alt="Evelyn Lauder" </img> <br>
</div>
<div style= width: 50%; class="text-center font-italic">
  <h7> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps try "max-width", and also put it in quotes. Consider what it's 50% of, too.

Comment: Why are your classes more like inline css?

Answer (score 3):

Your error would be revealed if you had [used a validator](https://validator.nu).

> ```
> <div style = width: 50%; class = "text-center font-italic">
> ```

Quotes around attribute values are **required** if the attribute value contains space characters.

```
<div style="width: 50%;" class="text-center font-italic">
```

NB: You have a number of other errors that the validator will point you towards.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this piece of code.

```
<div class = "text-center"> 
<h1 >Evelyn Lauder </h1>
<h5 class = "font-italic" > 1936-2011</h5>
<img src = "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg" alt = "Evelyn Lauder"> <br>

<div style="width: 50%;margin: 0 auto;"><h7 > "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7> </div>

</div>
```

Add style to div. Hope it helps.!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.
Apply `display:inline-block` to your caption text. That's it :)

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Evelyn Lauder </h1>
  <h5 class="font-italic"> 1936-2011</h5>
  <img src=http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02093/lauder_2093473b.jpg alt="Evelyn Lauder" </img> <br>
</div>    
  <h7 style="width:50%; display:inline-block; font-style:italic;" class="text-center"> "Evelyn Lauder was an Austrian American businessman who was well known for popularzing the pink ribbon associated with breast cancer awareness." </h7>
```